# google test adapter vs 2017

Tags: adapter, googletest

I have successfully got "google test adapter" v 0.11.1 working on a laptop with vs 2017 community.
However, on my desktop (much preferred machine for coding), also running vs 2017 community,  despite being able to install it (apparently flawlessly) the option for Google tests in the new project menu is just simply not there.

I have uninstalled and re-installed "google test adapter" several times.
Each time the install appears successful (because I can find it to uninstall it) in extensions and updates. However, never does it appear as a project option.

I cannot see what more to do to solve this inexplicable conundrum.
I would appreciate some help...

I have an update:
There was a one version difference of google test adapter between the two computer systems - v 0.11.1 and v 0.10.1.
Version 0.10.1 works properly and version 0.11.1 does not!
So the latest version is somehow problematic - what the issue is I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having that problem, please open an issue on the [Google Test Adapter GitHub page](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter).